# EWS - Get Throttling Policy

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I need to get the parameter values of Get-ThrottlingPolicy for Exchange 2013. I am looking at getting the values.

Is it possible to get this through EWS API? 
I have tried extracting this through powershell from C#. I am not able to find the cmdlet Get-ThrottlingPolicy. What is the solution, what could be wrong. I am new to powershell.

Also can we retrieve the current status - ex current concurrency.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: No progress. Dropped this idea, did not find any solution

Answer (score 1):

Sadly doesn't look like is possible. The github repo does not appear to contain any reference to throttling.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/search?q=throttling

Comment: Any more solutions to this?